# Assigning keys from rows of one table to rows to another concurrency concerns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

In the users table I am adding new rows, these rows need to each contain a reference the id of a unique row in another "access keys" table.

Some of these users rows may be added simultaneously from many threads.  I know these will be database blocking with the writes so not truly simultaneously.  So maybe this is not a concern?

So I have a php script that creates the new user row, and I have the access keys table populated with many rows.  How do I generate the reference to the id of a unique row in the "access keys" table and how do I know it is unique?

Comment: Please show us some code - the PHP, the database structure, your current SQL, etc...

Comment: if each user needs a single unique access key, why not just make "access_key" a column/unique key in the users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it sequentially from whatever thread(s) are doing the insertion:

1) add row to the users table
2) retrieve ID of this new row
3) insert into access keys table using the ID retrieved in #2
4) go to 1) until completed

MySQL can securely return the last ID it created as part of an insert query for each connection - an insert done by some OTHER thread will not overwrite another thread's "last insert id" - the last insert id kept on a per-connection basis.

With this structure, you can have as many threads as you want doing inserts, and none of them will step on each other's toes, as they're all getting their own distinct "last id".

Comment: How do I find an unused row in the "access keys" table and know it is still unused by the time I put a user id in it?

Comment: Don't pre-generate the access keys, if that's what you're getting at. While not totally secure, even a simple `md5(user_id)` id field would generate a "key".

Comment: The access keys are already pregenerated.  I am not the one generating them.  I need some kind of counter variable that exists in memory which all running scripts can access it seems like...

Comment: Ok, in that case each key gets its own unique key, then a parralel table you can insert to generates those ids as you insert. so you go user<->assignment<->keys

Answer (score 2):

"What I mean is how do I get the next "access keys" id that is not currently assigned to any users row. How do I keep track of which have not yet been used in order to know which one to write in the users table."

If you want this to work with an absolute guarantee of things never going wrong, then all your "add user" transactions should be fully serialized.  I.e. they cannot possibly execute concurrently.

It is impossible to get a definite answer to the question "which access keys are currently not in use" while any transaction is going on that might be in the very process of changing the answer to that very question.

Instead of retrieving prepared access keys from a pool, can you generate access keys by hashing userid or user names or something like that ?  If so, I'd do that.

If not, you'll have to either accept the full serialization (i.e. transaction delay and possibly the occasional transaction timeout), or else you'll have to accept the fact that things might go wrong.

Note that "accepting full serialization" need not be problematic.  If you keep your transactions short-lived (i.e. you commit them fast), then chances are you won't even notice the serialization.

Comment: How would I force them to serialize with php/sql?  Make some kind of long running process acting as a queue that the user generating script interacts with using curl somehow?

Comment: You'd have to configure your client-side stuff (client-side wrt the DBMS engine) such that the transactions in which it runs these updates, run in the serializable isolation level.  I have little interest in particular SQL engines, and so I don't know the details of how to do this in some particular SQL engine.

Comment: BTW, long-running transactions are exactly what you should _NOT_ do in such scenarios.